# Why does this stack variable not get overwritten although it is out of scope?

Tags: c++, pointers, stack

AFAIK, variables declared on the stack only live until the current scope ends, so basically until the next `}` comes up. However, let's take this example:

```cpp
int main() {
    int* ptrOne;
    {
        int intOne = 1;
        ptrOne = &intOne;
    }
    int intTwo = 9;

    std::cout << *ptrOne;
}
```

When `intTwo` is declared, `intOne` is already out of scope. It is no longer accessible and should thus get overwritten. However, the `cout` still works and puts out `1`. In the memory view, I can see that the 1 still exists, with the 9 written a few bytes behind it. Why? (I'm using Visual Studio 2019 with MSVC)

Comment: It's undefined behavior. Who knows what could happen?

Comment: *and should thus get overwritten.* -- Where did you get the idea that this is the case?   Never assume what the compiler does unless *you* wrote the code yourself and know what is done, or it is documented (in the C++ standard, by the compiler vendor, etc.) what is done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It is no longer accessible and should thus get overwritten.

Incorrect, the correct statement is `it is no longer accessible and so the program has undefined behaviour`. You can't reason about programs with undefined behaviour, they can do what they like.

Comment: But when do variables on the stack get deleted? Do these unaccessible ones just hang around forever until there's a stack overflow?

Comment: @CheeseCrustery In valid programs stack variables get deleted, in invalid programs anything can happen.

Comment: If you have a valid program it must follow the rules of C++, which means stack variables get destroyed (not deleted, that's something else). But invalid C++ programs don't have to follow the rules. They could do anything, that's what undefined behaviour means.

Comment: What else would the storage previously occupied by `intOne` be used for in this case?  `intTwo` isn't ever used, so there's no reason to store that into memory, and even if it was it would probably live entirely in a register unless you gave the compiler a reason that it really needed to get stored to memory.

Comment: @CheeseCrustery -- There is no guarantee those variables are in the stack.. They could have been optimized and placed in registers.

Comment: C++ is defined on an abstract machine, and in the abstract machine the object stops existing at the end of the block.  The compiler only has to make the actual machine reproduce the output that the abstract machine would produce for well-defined code .